# Transferring Steam Games Between Computers (Aiming to download only once)

Tags: file-transfer, steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move Steam games to new computer](https://superuser.com/questions/16943/move-steam-games-to-new-computer)

Just bought a couple cheap copies of Left for Dead on steam.

Can I download the game once on my computer and over ethernet transfer the files to another machine? I really don't want to download the 5 gig game more than once.

Thanks!

Comment: What a fantastic question. Only it is an exact duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/16943/move-steam-games-to-new-computer

Comment: Hey I think I remember answering this question alr.... oh wait! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Steam's backup feature](http://supportwiki.steampowered.com/wiki/Using_the_Steam_Backup_Feature).